# Regex to find a name from a paragraph

Tags: python, regex

I am performing a regex way to find name and address in an invoice.

I have tried the bellow regex patterns:

```
^([A-Za-z])+$
^[A-Za-z]+(((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Za-z])+))?$
^[A-Za-z]+((\s)?((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Za-z])+))*$
^[A-Za-z]+((\s)?([A-Za-z])+)*$
```

if not regex is there any other way to find the customer name & address in this given data?

the invoice data is bellow:

```
09/06/2020 Browntape.com | Orders | HtmlInvoice

Original for Receipient

Duplicate for Supplier/Transporter


TAX INVOICE Triplicate for Supplier

ITU TAMAA i

38826532-601 1257816 MLO380675700
comapy
GSTIN 1 29145AKCA223551ZK Invoice Date : 8 Jun 2020
Branch : Karnataka Invoice No. : SSINV/17-18/0887480
PAN =NA Reference No. : 38826532-601 1257816
Place of Supply AS Payment Type : PAID
Customer Name Billing Address Shipping Address
Saswati Saswati Saswati

Addreesss, Addreesss,
Customer GSTIN Khanamukh , Guwahati, AS, India, 781014 Khanamukh , Guwahati, AS, India, 781014
Ph: 1234567890 Ph: 1234567890

Pre-Tax Pre-Tax| pre-tax Taxable

Unit Unit -,
Discount| Shipping Oni NR tans

(INR) (INR)

Desc. of Goods

Z|1880COREABLUE032DD
(ZI1880COREABLUE032DD) 42.86 384.76


42.86 0 384.76


Taxable Amount

Total Tax
Invoice Total
Invoice Total(In Words) | INR Four Hundred and Four
We hope that you like the iterns that you have received. If there is anything about your products that you
are not happy with, please let us know using the contact details below and we will be happy to help you.
For Milastar Retail Pvt Ltd Authorised
We would be grateful for your positive feedback about our service. Signatory
Thank you for your business, we hope to see you again soon!
Warehouse Address: company, Warehouse no 2,
Company Address: company, Karnataka, addreess,
Karnataka, 562123, India, manjunath@zivame.com, company
app.browntape.com/orders/html_invoice/5561154968 Vi
```

My expected result is

```
Saswati Address: Khanamukh , Guwahati, AS, India, 781014 Khanamukh , Guwahati, AS, India, 781014
```

Comment: Please add your expected result too. It'll help.

Comment: Please show your required output, with precise note of formatting

Comment: Rather than single alternatives such as (\'|\-|\.), it is better to specify the equivalent character class [-'.]; this reduces the need for many escaped characters.
BTW: \' and \- do not need to be escaped in this case.

Comment: To match the customer name and address, you need to define the rules for finding them. For example, is a customer name and address always prefixed with the text "Customer" and followed by one or more terms each separated with a comma?

Comment: @Mandy8055 The expected result is :- It should print 
Name : Saswati 
Address: Khanamukh , Guwahati, AS, India, 781014 Khanamukh , Guwahati, AS, India, 781014

Comment: @niveditamadhava; looks like [**text mining**](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-mining-for-dummies-text-classification-with-python-98e47c3a9deb) which is too broad for a regex to achieve.

Comment: actually thats the problem @TonyR, according to pytessarct result, the data is bit different like its coming ""Customer Name Billing Address Shipping Address" after that we have "name" followed by in the new line "address"

Comment: @Mandy8055 will text mining works? okay i will try it out

Comment: @niveditamadhava; if the format of the input remains static(i.e. only names and addresses vary) then regex could be tried out. BUt if it is dynamic then surely you've to go for text mining. If it is static then for [**address**](https://regex101.com/r/QyihYP/4) and for [**name**](https://regex101.com/r/QyihYP/5)

Answer (score 0):

`Customer [A-Z]*\s(([\w\s]+,)*([\d\s]+))`
captures this particular example, but may need to be customised. The captured text can be further processed in Python with the group() method.

Comment: This matching `ABC 123,123,123,   `

Comment: True, but as I mentioned, the regex may need to be customised to match the format rules.

Comment: There is often a conflict between the effort involved in eliminating "false positives" and "false negatives". When the data is well-formed, as may be the case here, it is not necessary to "over-complicate" the regex, in accordance with the motto: "economy of accuracy".

Comment: @TonyR Sure, but a non-functioning or improperly functioning regular expression is not the most useful...